# Split string and get a substring of each element

Tags: c#, string, split, substring

I would like to split the string below using "|" as separator but would also like to extract only the strings after the colon (:) into the array:

Input:

> CompanyID:1234|CompanyName:ABC

Desired Output would be an array with values:

> 1234, ABC

Current code so far is:

```
string text = "CompanyID:1234|CompanyName:ABC";
string[] ids = text.Split('|');
```

Is there a way to do it in one line?

Appreciate anyone's help.

Thanks.

Comment: LINQ's `.Select` with another split?

Comment: You just need to apply `Split()` to the strings again and take the second element of the result. See duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hi I want to get a substring of each element, not just the second element, and output it as a string array. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
text.Split('|').Select(s => s.Split(':').Last()).ToArray()
```

Comment: Hi thank you. I need to get an output of string array with each element only containing the string after the colon.

Comment: @KateB added a call to ToArray(), I believe it should achieve what you are looking for

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!